# Vue computed function resulting in error when data added

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, computed-properties

In my jsbin here http://jsbin.com/fecukitisu/edit?html,js,output.  My total, and tax bindings are working until a user adds a new 'sale' via the included button.  I cannot figure out why the computed functions return NAN when another sale is added.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error with the return value of your component's data function. You have the "sale" property set to an array of objects.  It should just be an object.
Change this:

```
    data: function() {
      return {
        tip: 8.50,
        sale: [
            { price: '' },
            { desc: '' },
            { amount: '' }
        ]
      };
    }
```

To this:

```
    data: function() {
      return {
        tip: 8.50,
        sale: { 
            price: '',
            desc: '',
            amount: '' 
        }
      };
    }
```